# App name has -temp-caseinsensitive-rename attached to it

Tags: xcode

I have been having an issue when trying to rename my app. Basically I have clicked on my app's name under 'Project' and changed the name under 'Identity and Type' to the desired name. The issue is that when I run my app, the name under the icon appears as this:

testName-temp-caseinsensitive-rename

I gave my app the name 'testName' while I was checking whether it would work, but now it seems I am stuck with this and the weird temp-caseinsensitive-rename bit.

I have done a quick search but the results were no help to me so I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. I used the search function in Xcode and found the remaining places with 'testName-temp-caseinsensitive-rename' as the name. Product Name and Product Module Name still had that name set so I renamed them and it fixed the issue.